# Connections are not getting removed from connection pool in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0, toad

I am using c3p0 connection pool for pooling in my hibernate project.This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/minkme_active</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username">java</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password">java123</property>

    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>        
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">30</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">250</property>

    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>


<mapping resource="Save.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="ad.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="msgs.hbm.xml"/>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is my Snapshot ofrom TOAD for MYSQL: http://postimg.org/image/i45d3wri1/

Here i have set `idle_test_period` of 5 seconds so after every 5 seconds the ids of sessions change but i have also mentioned `timeout` of 30 seconds so after every 30 seconds the connections should be removed from database but that is not hapenning.

Comment: hibernate's c3p0 config param `idle_test_period`, which maps to c3p0's `idleConnectionTestPeriod` has nothing to do with hibernate sessions. it determines the frequency with which raw Connections managed by the pool and not checked out will be retested. every 30 seconds database Connections in the pool will be closed if and only if they have been idle, that is, your app is quiet enough that they are sitting in the pool and not checked out throughout that whole period.

Comment: @SteveWaldman So what do you suggest as you can see the threads are not getting killed.Why?

Comment: you are looking at some server-side tool. i've no idea what it is displaying. it certainly isn't "threads". if "sessions" map to client connections to the db (my best guess, but what do i know?), are you sure that the list is not cumulative? that is, perhaps closed sessions remain in the list, in which case you'd see the list grow endlessly over time. in any case, on the client side, c3p0 is using `numHelperThreads` + 1 (Timer thread) for each c3p0 DataSource.